# How to access google Play Developers console from a Google apps account

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-apps

I want to publish an android app on behalf of my company and thus I want to publish the app in google play. Though, when I try to access google play at [this url](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) using my google apps account I get the following message:

> We are sorry, but you do not have access to this service. Please log
>   in to your Admin Console to enable this service.

I have thus gone to my admin and enabled a Google Service called "Google Developers Console"- what appears to only be related with Google Cloud and to have nothing to to with Android. On the other hand, when enabling this service It was clear that it could take 24h until my user would have access to enabled service. Thus I am stuck waiting if I finally was able to enable the access to the android applications publishing facility or if this is the wrong way to go.

- Is 'Google Developers Console' the same thing as "Google Play
  Developers Console"?
- Does having permisions to access "Google Developers Console" allow me to publish android apps on google play?
- If not, then how can I register to use "Google Play Developers Console" with a google apps account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google's support, this is the way to go:

1. Log in to the Google Apps Control Panel and click "More controls" at the bottom of the screen.
2. Click "Other Google Services."
3. Remove the filter by clicking the "X" in the top right.
4. Select the Google Play Developer Console.
5. Click in the top left to enable or disable the Developer Console.

Comment: This caused us a great amount of confusion. I wish you had posted this answer last year and I wouldn't have created and published under my personal account!

Answer (score 3):

1. No they are not the same. You can use the Google Developers Console without ever using the Google Play Developers Console.

> Google Play Developers Console enables developers to easily publish and distribute their applications directly to users of Android-compatible phones.
>
> The Google Developers Console is Google's new developer experience for managing and viewing traffic data, authentication, and billing information for the Google APIs that your projects use.

basically you use the Google Developers Console to manage projects, create and delete projects, etc

2. To access Google Developer's Console,you need a Google account, you use same for publishing apps.